# Does an ethernet checksum include padding bits?

Tags: ethernet, layer2

For ethernet II (aka ethernet DIX) frames that are padded to contain 64 bytes total, is the checksum in the last 4 bytes computed with the padding bits as input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.
The whole point of the CRC is to verify the integrity of the frame on the medium.